# Return new array with specific values using map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please help me with a solution to extract in a new array only the specific object that has the paramenter checked: true.
See the example below:

```
    {nodeName: 'node1', nodeId: 1, checked: false },
    {nodeName: 'node2', nodeId: 2, checked: true },
    {nodeName: 'node3', nodeId: 3, checked: false },
    {nodeName: 'node4', nodeId: 4, checked: true },
    {nodeName: 'node5', nodeId: 5, checked: false },
    {nodeName: 'node6', nodeId: 6, checked: true },
]

let checkedNodes = nodes.map(node => {
    let options = {
        "name": node.nodeName,
        "id": node.nodeId,
        "checked": node.checked
    }
    
    return options;
})
```

This will return all the nodes :(
How can I make the verification, in order to return the array like this?

```
[
    {
        "name": "node2",
        "id": 2,
        "checked": true
    },
    {
        "name": "node4",
        "id": 4,
        "checked": true
    },
    {
        "name": "node6",
        "id": 6,
        "checked": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with just `.map()`. `.map()` will always return an array the same exact size of the input array.

You can either `.filter()` the array then `.map()`, or use `.reduce()`.

In this case, `.filter()` is going to be the easiest, both to read and write. Just include it before the `.map()` call:

```js
const nodes = [
  {nodeName: 'node1', nodeId: 1, checked: false },
  {nodeName: 'node2', nodeId: 2, checked: true },
  {nodeName: 'node3', nodeId: 3, checked: false },
  {nodeName: 'node4', nodeId: 4, checked: true },
  {nodeName: 'node5', nodeId: 5, checked: false },
  {nodeName: 'node6', nodeId: 6, checked: true },
]

const checkedNodes = nodes
  .filter(node => node.checked)
  .map(node => ({
    name: node.nodeName,
    id: node.nodeId,
    checked: node.checked
  }));
  
console.log(checkedNodes);
```

The only downside to this approach is it'll iterate over your list possibly twice, which is fine for small sets like this. If it was a large set of nodes, you'd want to consider using `.reduce()`, which could do it in one loop (at the cost of readability).

```js
const nodes = [
  {nodeName: 'node1', nodeId: 1, checked: false },
  {nodeName: 'node2', nodeId: 2, checked: true },
  {nodeName: 'node3', nodeId: 3, checked: false },
  {nodeName: 'node4', nodeId: 4, checked: true },
  {nodeName: 'node5', nodeId: 5, checked: false },
  {nodeName: 'node6', nodeId: 6, checked: true },
]

const checkedNodes = nodes
  .reduce((acc, node) => {
    if (node.checked) {
      acc.push({
        name: node.nodeName,
        id: node.nodeId,
        checked: node.checked
      })
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(checkedNodes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Map is inappropriate for this task - it is used to take a list of inputs and to produce an output for each input ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

You want to use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (for one result or undefined) or [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (for an array of 0 or or more matching objects).

```js
// Find the first checked node, or undefined if none are checked
const checkedNodes = nodes.find(node => node.checked);

// Find all checked nodes
const checkedNodes = nodes.filter(node => node.checked);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed, filter() is a way to extract and I will use map() after that.

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const nodes = [ {nodeName: 'node1', nodeId: 1, checked: false }, {nodeName: 'node2', nodeId: 2, checked: true }, {nodeName: 'node3', nodeId: 3, checked: false }, {nodeName: 'node4', nodeId: 4, checked: true }, {nodeName: 'node5', nodeId: 5, checked: false }, {nodeName: 'node6', nodeId: 6, checked: true } ];

const chekedNodes = nodes
  .filter(node => node.checked === true)
  .map(node => ({ name: node.nodeName, id: node.nodeId, checked: node.checked }));

console.log(chekedNodes);
```

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const nodes = [ {nodeName: 'node1', nodeId: 1, checked: false }, {nodeName: 'node2', nodeId: 2, checked: true }, {nodeName: 'node3', nodeId: 3, checked: false }, {nodeName: 'node4', nodeId: 4, checked: true }, {nodeName: 'node5', nodeId: 5, checked: false }, {nodeName: 'node6', nodeId: 6, checked: true } ];

const chekedNodes = nodes.reduce((list, node) => {
  if(node.checked === true) {
    list.push({ name: node.nodeName, id: node.nodeId, checked: node.checked });
  }
  return list;
}, []);

console.log(chekedNodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `filter` and `map` to get the desired array;

```
nodes.filter(n => n.checked)
  .map(n => ({id: n.nodeId,
    name: n.nodeName,
    checked})
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `filter()` method of array.
- below we are iterating though the array and returning `node` object whenever `node.checked` is true.

```js
let data = [{
    nodeName: 'node1',
    nodeId: 1,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    nodeName: 'node2',
    nodeId: 2,
    checked: true
  },
  {
    nodeName: 'node3',
    nodeId: 3,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    nodeName: 'node4',
    nodeId: 4,
    checked: true
  },
  {
    nodeName: 'node5',
    nodeId: 5,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    nodeName: 'node6',
    nodeId: 6,
    checked: true
  },
]
// we are using filter method of array and just returning node.checked is true.
let result = data.filter(node => {
  if (node.checked) {
    return node;
  }
});
console.log(result);
```